# Set selected status to an option tag

Tags: angular, angular7

I have a problem with setting selected status to an option tag in angular. What I really want is when the user refreshes the window option should be selected as the default by URL. Here is some snippet:

```
<div class="row mb-4">
  <div class="col-12">
    <select (change)="navigateTo($event.target.value)">
      <option
        *ngFor="let row of routes"
        [value]="row.value"
        [selected]="selected"
      >
      {{ 'khanbankCpmsApp.project.'+row.name | translate }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my `.ts` file:

```
selected: boolean = false;
navigateTo(valueUrl) {
  if (valueUrl) {
    this.router.navigate([valueUrl], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute});
    this.selected = !this.selected;
  }
  return false;
}
```

What did I do wrong? any advice?

Comment: Can you create a stackbiltz

Comment: All of your options are bound to the same `selected` property which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should set selected item on `<select>` tag:

```
<select (change)="navigateTo($event.target.value)" [value]="selectedItem">
```

when use `[selected]="selected"` in `*ngFor` last option will select.

Comment: Where those `selectedItem` getting from ?

Comment: try it:
```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private router:Router) { ... }


    selectedItem: string;
    ngOnInit() {
        selectedItem= this.router.url; 

    }

}
```

Comment: First initial i can not see any value

Comment: Please put the your components code here thoroughly

Comment: Please remove `[selected]="selected"` from option tag in template, and replace select tag by `<select (change)="navigateTo($event.target.value)" [value]="router.url">`

Answer (score 0):

Your `selected` property is the same for all options of the list.
So whenever it is true, it sets selected to every option in the dropdown... That obviously is not going to work.

What you need, is to instead store the current route url in a property, say `currentRoute` and then in your *ngFor loop do something like:
`[selected]="row.value === currentRoute"`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `[value]` of select to bind it to the current path.

Here is [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uf2mhs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpage.component.html)

In template

```
<select (change)="navigateTo($event.target.value)" [value]="getPath() | async">
  <option
    *ngFor="let row of routes"
    [value]="row.value"
  >
    {{ row.name }}
  </option>
</select>
```

and in component

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: './page.component.html',
  styles: [``]
})
export class PageComponent  {
  routes = [
    { name: 'A', value: '/a' },
    { name: 'B', value: '/b' },
    { name: 'C', value: '/c/a/b' }
  ];

  constructor(
    public route: ActivatedRoute,
    public router: Router,
  ) {}

  getPath() {
    return this.route.url.pipe(
      map(parts => '/' + parts.map(({ path }) => path).join('/')),
      filter((path) => path.length > 1), // ignore default empty path remove this and next line if you have routing correctly set up
      startWith(this.routes[0].value), // some startup value if you didn't setup routing
    )
  }

  navigateTo(path) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl(path)
  }
}
```

Comment: added setup to redirection check example stackblitz app.module configuration
`{ path: '', redirectTo: '/a', pathMatch: 'full' }` this will setup base selection you can also modify getPath() to return some default path

Comment: updated answer with default value if routing isn't configured